# Reloading dynamic code / reloading type

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection, .net-assembly

I ran into some issues in my current project and I'd really appreciate if someone could provide me with some insight, or possibly advice.

My project is a service, that is executing user scripts. Scripts are written in C# and I'm using CodeDomProvider to build an assembly at runtime. Assembly contains single class.

```
public Script : ScriptBase
{
    public override void Run(){}
}
```

User is allowed to change the script and if I detect a change. I rebuild the content creating new instance of a ScriptBase child. I know that the original assembly A1 with the script S1 stays loaded in the current AppDomain, but it is a price I'm willing to pay. This scenario works without any problem.

I wanted to add a capability for user defined libraries (also editable at runtime). So now the problem is I have a Script S1, that is using Library L1. If user changes L1, I obviously have to rebuild all the scripts. And here comes the problem:

```
build L1 with type T1
build S1 --depends--> L1
(use S1)
build L2 with type T1
build S2 --depends--> L2 = crashes type T1 is defined in L1 and L2
(use S1) //It passes through if I didn't use S1 for the first time
```

I have following questions

1. How comes that my first scenario works. I.e. I'm building and loading assemblies with the same type over and over again and everything works fine

   2.If I don't use S1 after it is build, I'm able to build the S2 even though when I check the Modules, I can see, that all assemblies L1,S1,L2,S2 were loaded. Apparently if I load assembly, but I don't use it somehow the "assembly is loaded, but type is not loaded". What is really going on?

   3.What would you suggest as a solution to my problem? It looks like the most logical would be to use temporary AppDomain, but I don't have any experience with that, it looks quite complicated and if there was a simpler solution I'd rather use it.

Thank you

Comment: I think the main answer here would be: either look to the use of an AppDomain (it really isn't that bad when you get the hang of it), or look to any of the existing scripting hosts; IronPython, IronRuby, ecmascript and Lua have pretty decent managed script hosts, IIRC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an AppDomain is the best bet here.  As Marc said, they are really not that bad once you know what you are doing, its just finding the info that I found a problem.

Now, shameless plug: I made this repository for another question on StackOverflow to help with reflection loading assemblies, and it should cover the basics of setting up an AppDomain an communicating with it across boundaries: [Plugin Demo](https://github.com/Pondidum/PluginDemo)

From the look of your question, you can safely ignore the Shadow Copying part, and just use the Scanner/communication part of the Host project.

Comment: Well, I expected from the answer, that somebody would also explain what decides about when a Type is loaded from the assembly. Anyways, your example was extremely helpful and I thank you for that very much.